# Locating a label element using karate locators

Tags: karate

I have the following DOM. I want to extract the label below with text 'Click Me' so i can click on it. Have not been successful. Was wondering if someone can help what karate based locater strategy to use:

```
<div data-toggle="buttons" class="btn-vertical">
 <label type="button" class="btn-default">
  <input name="test" type="radio" value="HELLO" checked>
  "Click Me"
 </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these:

```
* click('{}Click Me')
* click('{}"Click Me"')
* click('input[name=test]')
* click("input[name='test']")
* click("input[@name='test']")
```

Do let me know which works ! Here is a tip, if you are able to use the VS Code debug support, you can type `highlight('{}Click Me')` etc into the "debug console" at the bottom of the screen and test various options while the app is running: https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1167533484560142336

Comment: I think the 'Click Me' is the label text for <label> tag. When i search using locators for label it does not work. So I searched using the radio button input and was able to find using:
`* click("input[value='Click Me']")`